# NHibernate Not Compile on my Window Server

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

My Apps was developed with NHibernate Working fine on my system but giving this error on the host Server

Index was outside the bounds of the array. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
   NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect.IsQuoted(String name) +84
   NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect.QuoteForSchemaName(String schemaName) +20
   NHibernate.Cfg.HbmBinder.MakeIdentifier(XmlNode node, SimpleValue model, Mappings mappings) +228
   NHibernate.Cfg.HbmBinder.BindRootClass(XmlNode node, RootClass model, Mappings mappings) +1223
   NHibernate.Cfg.HbmBinder.BindRoot(XmlDocument doc, Mappings mappings) +398
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddValidatedDocument(XmlDocument doc, String name) +69

[MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: CMS.Common.Mapping.CMS.Common.Data.AccountPeriod.hbm.xml]
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(MappingException me) +40
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddValidatedDocument(XmlDocument doc, String name) +137
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddXmlReader(XmlTextReader hbmReader, String name) +29
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddInputStream(Stream xmlInputStream, String name) +109
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddResource(String path, Assembly assembly) +185
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddResources(Assembly assembly, IList resources, Boolean skipOrdering) +166
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean skipOrdering) +32
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddAssembly(String assemblyName) +150
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.DoConfigure(XmlDocument doc) +644
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure(XmlTextReader reader) +304
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure(XmlNode node) +81
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure() +35
   ProjectBase.Data.NHibernateSessionManager.InitSessionFactory() +60
   ProjectBase.Data.NHibernateSessionManager..ctor() +39
   ProjectBase.Data.Nested..cctor() +39

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Nested' threw an exception.]
   ProjectBase.Data.NHibernateSessionManager.get_Instance() +38
   CMS.Facade.CoreSystem.BuildSession() in C:\Users\Oladapo\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Property Manager\CMS.Facade\CoreSystem.cs:440
   CMS.Facade.AdvertSystem.RetrieveAllAdvert() in C:\Users\Oladapo\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Property Manager\CMS.Facade\AdvertSystem.cs:16

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) +0
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) +71
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +350
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +29
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.InvokeMethod(ObjectDataSourceMethod method, Boolean disposeInstance, Object& instance) +488
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1247
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.GetData() +38
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource) +153
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +54
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.DataBind() +55
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.EnsureDataBound() +60
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.CreateChildControls() +69
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +87
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +44
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842

Answer (score 0):

After adding some NHibernate goodness to a project, I had similar problems deploying because I forgot to update the web.config file on production.  Once I defined the **hibernate-configuration** section, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Also happened to me when I had an empty **enum** defined.

Answer (score 0):

That you have a MappingException included in your stack trace is key.  This implies either a problem with your class mappings, or your NHibernate configuration.  It could also be that your database does not contain tables or fields defined in your class mappings.

To be more specific, you would need to provide additional information.